# How to not match documents in subarray of elements inside MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a sample data like below where I want to pull the result with only data not containing restrictions.validations.level: ERROR.

I need use the $match inside pipeline.

```
{
    "id": "123",
    "name": "A",
    "restrictions": [
        {
            "validations": [
                {
                    "level": "ERROR"
                },
                {
                    "level": "WARNING"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": "123",
    "name": "B",
    "restrictions": [
        {
            "validations": [
                {
                    "level": "WARNING"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I need the result below:

```
{
    "id": "123",
    "name": "B",
    "restrictions": [
        {
            "validations": [
                {
                    "level": "WARNING"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

already tried this and it doesn't work:

```
[
        { 
            "$match" : { 
                "id" : "123", 
                "restrictions" : { 
                    "$elemMatch" : { 
                        "validations" : { 
                            "$not" : { 
                                "$elemMatch" : { 
                                    "level" : "ERROR"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
```

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

```
[
        { 
            "$match" : { 
                "id" : "123", 
                "restrictions.validations" : { 
                    "$not" : { 
                        "$elemMatch" : { 
                            "level" : "ERROR"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
]
```